# selenium javascript textarea value wrong

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium

I have a webpage with javascript in which I've created a textarea like so

```
var textarea = $("<textarea>");
textarea.change(() => {
    console.log(textarea.val());
});
```

So when I change the value in the textarea and then change focus, the value is printed. This works as expected when using a normal web browser.

However, I have a test using selenium firefox driver that edits the textarea. Two seperate textareas are created using the same bit of code similar to above. The first one works fine. But with the second, selenium finds the textarea, sends keys, and tabs away, but `textarea.val()` returns an empty string. In the browser opened by selenium, I can see that the keys I sent are indeed entered in the textarea.

The code in my tests (python) that edits the textarea is

```
e.clear()
e.send_keys(s)
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.TAB).perform()
```

And as I said, I can inspect the browser that selenium creates, and the text has been entered and I have tabbed away. I also know this works because the change callback is called.

So why would `textarea.val()` in the js script return an empty string?

**UPDATE 1**

Another weird thing, if I leave the selenium-created browser open after the test fails and manually change the value in the textarea (the same exact one that just produced this error!), it works as expected! This led me to think it was some kind of timing issue. So I added 2 second sleep statements all over my test script, but no help.

**UPDATE 2**

While running my test with all the sleep statements, I notice that the first time the textarea is editted, the insert cursor appears in the textarea (as it should). But the second time, no cursor appears, even though the text is still entered properly using `send_keys`. I tried adding `e.click()` on the textarea after `e.clear()` it, but the cursor still doesnt appear. Perhaps the lack of cursor is related to my issue.

Comment: imo it's because you have 2 textareas. You are selecting `$("<textarea>")`, without uniquely identifying which one you actually want

Comment: @KirilS. I thought that in jquery, when you put valid html in the query like I've done here, jquery creates a new element instead of searching for now elements

Comment: I am not a specialist in jquery, so maybe it also is used to create element, but I've seen that syntax as selector: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: You can see an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp) of using the syntax I used to create an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried many things. Tried GPT14's answer. Tried changing my element.click() statements to ActionChains statements thinking that maybe the textarea wasnt being focused properly. In the end the only thing that worked was switching to the Chrome driver...

Still have strange behavior though, the textarea change callback gets called twice. The first time, it give an empty string. But the second time it returns the currect value and so my test is able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Tab out of the text area you need to press the tab key down and then release it. Your code is not releasing the Tab key which is why the `textArea.change()` is never triggered. Modify your code to

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.TAB).perform()
```

Comment: Tried this but it didnt help